# Error in TiDB: `java.sql.BatchUpdateExecption:statement count 5001 exceeds the transaction limitation`

Tags: sqoop, distributed-database, tidb

When I was using Sqoop to write data into TiDB in batches, I ran into the following error:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateExecption:statement count 5001 exceeds the transaction limitation
```

I configured the `--batch` option already, but this error still occurred. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

In Sqoop, `--batch` means committing 100 `statement`s in each batch, but by default each `statement` contains 100 SQL statements. So, 100 * 100 = 10000 SQL statements, which exceeds 5000, the maximum number of statements allowed in a single TiDB transaction.

Two solutions:

- Add the `-Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=10` option as follows:

  ```
  sqoop export \
      -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=10 \
      --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop \
      --username sqoop ${user} \
      --password ${passwd} \
      --table ${tab_name} \
      --export-dir ${dir} \
      --batch
  ```
- You can also increase the limited number of statements in a single TiDB transaction, but this will consume more memory.